# Customizing Menu Items Shortcut keys at Run Time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I need to provide a feature of assigning shortcut keys to any file menu item or buttons at runtime by a user. I am using Visual Studio 2012. Please suggest the standard method to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

Storing shortcuts in config file is an option. I am searching for the best regarding

> 1. Showing shortcut keys along with menu items
> 2. Some other commands too will be included which may or may not be
>      shown in menu

I am lookiing for standard way to proceed not the code. Is storing in config file the best way, what should I consider if any key is changed by user at runtime other than updating config file. This will be some sort of user specific preferences.

Comment: ***I need to keep a feature*** The answer to how keep a feature is simple: Do nothing.

Comment: I want the users to assign the shortcut cut keys themselves at run time. Suggest Please ?

Comment: It's as simple as storing the shortcuts in a configuration file and assigning them when starting the application. What's so hard about it? Show us where you have a problem and not "how to do X". Stack overflow is not a coding service, we are here to help you when you have a concrete issue when trying to code such a mechanism. But you have done nothing on your own until now. Voted to close

Comment: Thanks for reply. Please see my update in question

Answer (score 0):

```
private void AssignKey(ToolStripMenuItem item, string keyName)
    {
        try
        {
            Keys key = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), keyName);
            item.ShortcutKeys = key;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown key " + keyName);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Missed the update.

Anywho, just store the shortkeys in a "config" class, that has a Save method and save the it every time the software is closed.